# Is there a particular recommendation of exponent to use on the cost function when trying to do curve fitting in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have been doing some custom curve fits in `R` and I noticed that using the square of the difference between curve and data resulted in results that are very sensitive to the initial conditions, while using absolute value gives the exact same result in a reasonable neighborhood around the real parameters.

I suppose that squared terms reach a value below `.Machine$double.eps` faster, which stops the optimization early, but I would like confirmation and also some information regarding recommended cost functions for curve fitting.

Answer (score 0):

On my curve and surface fitting web site I have the following options for cost functions, each has a different fitting goal. For example, fitting to the lowest relative error squared means that a 5% error on the lowest value fits as well as a 5% error on the highest value, useful for some wide dynamic range fitting problems. Fitting to the lowest peak absolute error can sometimes be used for robust regression. The last two, AIC and BIC, can sometimes be useful when choosing between different models.

- Lowest sum of squared absolute error (classic OLS)
- Lowest sum of squared orthogonal distance
- Lowest sum of squared relative error
- Lowest sum of absolute value of absolute error
- Lowest sum of squared log[abs(predicted/actual)]
- Lowest sum of absolute value of relative error
- Lowest peak absolute value of absolute error
- Lowest peak absolute value of relative error
- Lowest Akaike Information Criterion
- Lowest Bayesian Information Criterion